# how to exclude weekend days in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am selecting two dates.

fromDate:mm/dd/yy

toDate:mm/dd/yy,

so I want the function which should exclude weekends so I tried this...

```
  function onblur(event){
      GetDaysBetweenDates();
  }

      function GetDaysBetweenDates(){     
          if(document.getElementById('datepicker3').value != ""){
              var fromDate = new Date(document.getElementById('datepicker2').value);
              var toDate = new Date(document.getElementById('datepicker3').value);        
              var timeDiff = Math.abs(toDate.getTime() - fromDate.getTime());
              var days = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));  

              if(days){
                    // Subtract two weekend days for every week in between
                    var weeks = Math.floor(days / 7);
                    days = days - (weeks * 2);

                    // Handle special cases
                    var startDay = fromDate.getDay();
                    var endDay = toDate.getDay();

                    // Remove weekend not previously removed.
                    if (startDay - endDay > 1)
                        days = days - 2;

                    // Remove start day if span starts on Sunday but ends before Saturday
                    if (startDay == 0 && endDay != 6)
                        days = days - 1;

                    // Remove end day if span ends on Saturday but starts after Sunday
                    if (endDay == 6 && startDay != 0)
                        days = days - 1;
                }

              $("#txtno_of_leaves").val(diffDays);
          }
      }
```

but this one is not working..

Comment: did it worked for you?

Comment: upvote also if it is working for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
function workingDaysBetweenDates(startDate, endDate, getWorkingDays) {

    startDate = new Date(startDate);
    endDate = new Date(endDate);

    // Validate input
    if (endDate < startDate)
        return 0;

    // Calculate days between dates
    var millisecondsPerDay = 86400 * 1000; // Day in milliseconds
    startDate.setHours(0,0,0,1);  // Start just after midnight
    endDate.setHours(23,59,59,999);  // End just before midnight
    var diff = endDate - startDate;  // Milliseconds between datetime objects
    var days = Math.ceil(diff / millisecondsPerDay);

    if(getWorkingDays){
        // Subtract two weekend days for every week in between
        var weeks = Math.floor(days / 7);
        days = days - (weeks * 2);

        // Handle special cases
        var startDay = startDate.getDay();
        var endDay = endDate.getDay();

        // Remove weekend not previously removed.
        if (startDay - endDay > 1)
            days = days - 2;

        // Remove start day if span starts on Sunday but ends before Saturday
        if (startDay == 0 && endDay != 6)
            days = days - 1;

        // Remove end day if span ends on Saturday but starts after Sunday
        if (endDay == 6 && startDay != 0)
            days = days - 1;
    }
    return days;
}

workingDaysBetweenDates(start_date, end_date, true);
```

Here is the working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kailashyadav/YXTX3/

Date format needs be one of these: `04/24/2014` or `2014-04-24`

Comment: @user3448105 Did it solved your issue? Let me know, if you face any issues

Comment: I have changed some code to get days in my way thats way it not working.can point out where I am going wrong?

Comment: check `days` variable was undefined in `if(diffDays)`

Comment: @user3448105 Also make sure you have `startDate.setHours(0,0,0,1);  //Start just after midnight` and `endDate.setHours(23,59,59,999);  // End just before midnight` statements to get exact days difference.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51109/discussion-between-kailash-yadav-and-user3448105)